# Spring Boot ApplicationRunner runs during startup - not after

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-task

I've created a class that implements the ApplicationRunner interface. As of my understanding the `public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments)` method should run after the application has completed its startup, but in my case it runs during the startup. Once my code has been executed the application completes its startup and logs the following just before exiting:

```
2020-03-31 17:52:24.303  INFO 9016 --- [           main] com.example.config.Application         : Started Application in 22.586 seconds (JVM running for 25.505)
```

This normally woulnd't be a problem for me, but this particular project is a Spring Cloud Task. Since my code gets executed during startup and Spring Cloud Tasks register their start time after the application has completely initialized I end up with wrong starting times that differ with the end times just by milliseconds. Also this implies that if my code errors out and fails to execute the task won't be able to record its starting time and exit code.

Whats the right way to solve this issue?

Comment: What if you depend your ApplicationRunner bean on other beans using @DependsOn?

Comment: My ApplicationRunner bean already is one of the last beans to run. It depends on another bean that takes 10-15 seconds to fully initialize